# Unable to cast an IEnumerable to a known type

Tags: vb.net, linq, casting

I have `ocPeople`, an `ObservableCollection(of Person)` and want to do the following:

```
Dim Attendees As IEnumerable = (From p In ocPeople
                                        Where (p.TypeID = 24)
                                        Select p.PersonID, p.FullName
                                        Order By FullName).Cast(Of People)
        For Each Attendee As Person In Attendees
            <some code>
        Next
```

but I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'VB$AnonymousType_0`2[System.Int64,System.String]' to type 'People'.

I don't understand why this throws an error.

**Update:**
The problem is not with the Linq, it arises from the For...Next loop.  Even if I turn Option Infer On, and write the for statement as:

```
For Each Attendee in Attendees
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you do a Select. The result of the Select is not a People object, but an anonymous object containing a PersonId and a FullName.

If your People object contains only a PersonId and a FullName you should select the complete p:

```
Select p
Order By ...
```

If you don't want the selected People object, but a new People object that contains the PersonId and the FullName of the selected People object, you should create a new People object in your Select.

Alas I'm not familiar with how yo create a new object in visual basic, but it will be similar to the folowing:

```
select new People(p.PersonId, p.FullName)
order by ...
```

This is probably wrong, but you get the gist

**The error appears in the foreach**

The reason that you get your error in the foreach, is because the Linq statement does not create the sequence, it creates the possibility to enumerate the sequence.

As long as you don't enumerate over your sequence, your original collection is not queried.

Enumerating over the collection is done when you do a foreach, or when you use a non-deferred execution statement like ToList(), FirstOrDefault(), Any(), Sum(), etc. Whether a Linq function uses deferred execution is described in the comments section of every Linq function

Your run-time error is about the enumeration of your sequence, not about the creation of your enumerable. That is why you get if only when you enumerate over it.